# How can I set AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser for only my Silverlight app?

Tags: security, silverlight-5.0

I am creating Silverlight applications using Silverlight 5 with "Require Elevated Trust when Run In-Browser" Setting true. I want to the user to select a folder and then application uploads all files from the selected folder. This behavior demands application to have elevated rights and must have "AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser" entry with value "1" in registry.

Now setting this registry entry to true will affect every Silverlight application. Can I set such entry in registry so that only my application will enjoy this setting and other Silverlight applications have to set this permission at their own?

Sorry for bad description but what I want is to access the file system and what I don't want is to open the permission channel for every trusted Silverlight applications.

Comment: +1 Good question. I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the answer is (at present) - no.  But I also think the answer (in the future) should be - yes.  It makes sense for a fully-trusted 'named' Silverlight application to run in-browser provided the user has agreed for this to be so (i.e. they are given the choice in a pop-up)